# Can't insert data in payment table

Tags: php, codeigniter

Does anyone here know why I can't insert my data in my payment table? I just want to insert it but I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\acz-thesis\app\models\account.php:565

Line 565: `$total_amount = $row['sales_net_amount'];`

**Controller**

```
public function InsertPaymentSales() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['token']) == $this->input->post('token')) {
        $data = array(
            'payment_amount'    => $this->input->post('payment_amount'),
            'payment_date'      => $this->input->post('payment_date'),
            'payment_remark'    => $this->input->post('payment_remark'),
            'payment_balance'   => $this->input->post('payment_balance'),
            'payment_sales_id'  => $this->input->post('payment_sales_id')
        );
        $this->model('account')->sales_payment($data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function sales_payment($data) {
    $payment_amount     = $data['payment_amount'];
    $payment_date       = $data['payment_date'];
    $payment_remark     = $data['payment_remark'];
    $payment_balance    = $data['payment_balance'];
    $payment_sales_id   = $data['payment_sales_id'];

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT sales_net_amount, sales_balance FROM tbl_sales_details WHERE sales_id = $payment_sales_id");
    $row = $query->fetch_object();
    $total_amount = $row['sales_net_amount'];
    $balance = $row['sales_balance'];

    if($payment_amount >= $payment_balance && $balance > 0) {
        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_sales_payments (payment_amount, payment_date, sales_id, payment_remarks) 
        VALUES($payment_amount, '$payment_date', $payment_sales_id, '$payment_remark')");
        if($query) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(payment_amount) as  total_payments FROM tbl_sales_payments WHERE sales_id = $payment_sales_id"); 
            $row = $query->fetch_object();
            $total_payments = $row['total_payments'];
            $total_balance = $total_amount - $total_payments;

            $query = $this->db->query("UPDATE tbl_sales_details SET sales_balance = $total_balance WHERE sales_id = $payment_sales_id");
            $message = 'Success';
            $query ? notify('success', $message, true) : null;
        }
    } else {
        $message = 'Error';
        notify_amaran([false,'#4caf50','#fff',$message]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You use [fetch_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) to get your data, which is saved in an object. You access object attributes via `->`, and not by `[<array index>]`. Change the error line to `$total_payments = $row->total_payments;`

Comment: You mean this? public function post($data) {
            return $data == 'comment' ? $this->db->real_escape_string($_POST[$data]) : $this->db->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST[$data]));
        }

Comment: Btw, thanks for your help! It's working now!

Comment: btw, you are using codeigniter framework, why don't you take advantage of the framework's [query builder class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder) and to [Generating Query Results](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

`$row = $query->fetch(); $total_amount = $row['sales_net_amount'];`

I think that using fetch_object() on $query returns an object instead of an associative array that you want to use with `$row['sales_net_amount']`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Definitely not Rafal   has already commented you cannot access attributes as array

These lines are wrong

```
  $total_amount = $row['sales_net_amount'];
  $balance = $row['sales_balance'];

    [..]
    $total_payments = $row['total_payments'];
```

change those to

```
$total_amount = $row->sales_net_amount;
$balance = $row->sales_balance;
[..]
$total_payments = $row->total_payments;
```